# WSL(ubuntu) printf only outputs the same text

Tags: c, printf

I have a problem. My code:

```cc
#include <stdio.h>

int readInteger() {
        int x,y;
        printf("variable 1 :");
        scanf("%d", &x);
        return x;
        printf("variable 2 :");
        scanf("%d", &y);
        return y;
}

int compare (int, int);

int main() {
        int x = readInteger(x);
        int y = readInteger(y);
        printf("%d is greater", compare(x,y));
        return 0;
}

int compare(int x , int y) {
        if(x > y) return x;
        else return y;
}
```

only outputs

```
variable 1: ...
variable 1: ...
```

instead of

```
variable 1: ...
variable 2: ...
```

Comment: Overclocking is irrelevant. WSL is irrelevant. The computer is doing exactly what you told it to. Do you know what `return` does?

Comment: If you're expecting the function to pick up where it left off after a `return`, it doesn't work like that. Functions start at the top of every call. Also, you shouldn't be passing anything to your function.

Comment: Please read the document for what return does. You can find everything related to it on geeksforgeeks or tutorialspoint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is because `return` means "end function execution here". So, you have

```cc
int readInteger() {
        int x,y;
        printf("variable 1 :");
        scanf("%d", &x);
        return x;
        printf("variable 2 :");
        scanf("%d", &y);
        return y;
}
```

which, because of the `return x` line, is equivalent to

```cc
int readInteger() {
        int x,y;
        printf("variable 1 :");
        scanf("%d", &x);
        return x;
}
```

One quick fix is to remove `return x;` line. Though then it won't do exactly what you want the function to do, since you want to read 2 integers and return them.

A better fix is to pass the string to the function as argument and then call it twice:

```cc
int readInteger(const char* prompt) {
        int x;
        printf(prompt);
        scanf("%d", &x);
        return x;
}

int main() {
        int x = readInteger("variable 1 :");
        int y = readInteger("variable 2 :");
        printf("%d is greater", compare(x,y));
        return 0;
}
```

PS. If a function has no arguments (`readInteger` in your original code, you should not call it with arguments (`int x = readInteger(x)` in `main`).

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I just had to change "printf(prompt)" to "printf("%s", Prompt)" because gcc gave an error with your version.